# Linear algorithm for 2D array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, big-o

I have a 1D array `A` filled with integers (`A[0]` to `A[n]`). I am questioned to design a linear algorithm that makes a 2D array `B` where `B[i][j] = A[i] + ... + A[j]` for `0 <= i < j <= n`. So this means I need to loop over all elements above the diagonal, so `(n-1) x n x (1/2)` elements so `O(n^2)`. I started my algorithm (pseudocode) by the following:

```
for i=0 to n-1:
    for j=i+1 to n:
        // do calc
```

But this is already `O(n^2)`, is linear time even possible?

Comment: No. You can't get below `O(n^2)`. The best you can do is `Theta(n^2)`, but you've got `Theta(n^2)` fields that need to be filled, so you can't possibly get below that lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to fill a 2D array with the size of `n^2`, the time complexity of the algorithm is `Omega(n^2)`. Hence, it is not possible to run this algorithm in linear time under the current specification.